# MapController and google map marker not working

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, geolocation

So am using the google map marker in flutter, but it not working, instead it showing "Undefined name 'mapController'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name"

Here is my code:

```
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller){

    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }
}

 _addMarker() {
  var marker = MarkerOptions(

    position: mapController.cameraPosition.target,
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    infoWindowText: InfoWindowText('Magic Marker', '')
  );

  mapController.addMarker(marker);
}
```

These are the dependencies used:

```
  geoflutterfire: "^2.0.2"
  location: "^1.4.1"
  google_maps_flutter: "^0.2.0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your GoogleMap widget code?

Comment: can u paste more code of your class ?